# Type Mismatch with polymorphism in ArrayLists

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, polymorphism

Here is my code:-

```
ArrayList<animal> myanimals = new ArrayList<animal>();
dog adog = new dog();
myanimals.add(adog);
System.out.println("" + myanimals.get(0).getClass());
dog newdog = myanimals.get(0);
```

I have created an `ArrayList` of **animals(superclass)** as `myanimals`  and stored a **dog(subclass)** as the first element. Then `myanimals.get(0)` returns a dog type object. When this dog type object is referred by a dog type reference in the statement `dog newdog = myanimals.get(0)`, it shows an error saying :

> Type mismatch, cannot convert from animal to dog.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow. Please post the code and error as text, not as an Image

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. @Shashwat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method call `myanimals.get(0)` returns an object reference of type `Animal`. Try **Typecasating** that `Animal` as a `dog` like :-

```
dog newdog = (dog)myanimals.get(0);
```

**Edit 1**: You asked about the output of the following line

```
System.out.println(myanimals.get(0).getClass());
```

This actually prints out `dog`. Why ? Let's get some perspective.

What do you think the following program should output:

```
animal a = new dog();
System.out.println(a.getClass());
```

This prints out `dog` as expected. But this doesn't mean that we can do this:-

```
animal a = new dog();
dog d = a;
```

This would throw a **Compile-Time** error. The Same is the problem with your case. The `ArrayList` is said to contain `animal`. Therefore, it would return `animal` even though you added a `dog` to it.

Comment: But the command : **System.out.println("" + myanimals.get(0).getClass());** shows output as **"class polymorph.dog"**. Doesn't this mean that the **myanimals.get(0)** returns a dog object?

Comment: While correct, this does not answer OPs question about "why" it is not allowed

Comment: @AayushTaneja See my answer now. I hope this edit clears thing up.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a statically typed language. I.e. Java compiler checks code for type mismatches based on source code. And your source code says, that  `myanimals.get(0)` is of type Animal.

Inheritance is a "IS-A" relationship, i.e. Dog IS-A Animal and can be used as value for variables of type Animal. But the reverse is not true: Animal not IS-A Dog, it just could be (which makes casting possible - more on that later). That's why you get type mismatch.

It is only in runtime, long after your source code had been compiled into bytecode (and generics types erased), that `myanimals.get(0).getClass()` appears to be Dog by coincidence. Compiler couldn't know that before.

This makes sense: it prevents runtime errors that could be caught by static analysis.

But it's you, the developer, who knows for sure, that `myanimals.get(0).getClass()` will be of type Dog at runtime, so you can take responsibility and apply casting as in Shashwat's answer. Compiler still checks if such casting is possible at all, and if yes - it would believe your word.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. @iTollu

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the type of an ArrayList is `animal` and you could add any kind of animals in there, not just dogs but cats, mice and parrots. While the underlying type is indeed `dog` in your case, you can't safely know this. Otherwise you'd run into runtime exceptions as in this scenario:

```
ArrayList<Animal> myanimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
Cat myCat = new Cat();
myanimals.add(myCat);
System.out.println("" + myanimals.get(0).getClass());
Dog newdog = myanimals.get(0); // <-- this would be runtime exception if Java compiler allowed this
```